# SQL - select only results having multiple entries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

this seems simple but I cannot figure out how to do it or the proper description to correcltly google it :(

Briefly, have a table with:

```
PatientID | Date | Feature_of_Interest...
```

I'm wanting to plot some results for patients with multiple visits, when they have the feature of interest. No problem filtering out by feature of interest, but then I only want my resulting query to contain patients who have multiple entries.

```
SELECT PatientID,Date,...
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Feature_Of_Interest is present
    AND (Filter out PatientID's that only appear once)
```

So - just not sure how to approach this. I tried doing:

```
WITH X AS (Above SELECT, Count(*),...,Group by PatientID)
```

Then re-running query, but it did not work. I can post that all out if needed, but am getting the impression I am approaching this completely backward, so will defer for now.

Using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to join a subquery

```
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        PatientID
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE Feature_Of_Interest is present 
    GROUP BY PatientID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) s ON myTable.PatientID = s.PatientID
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH qry AS
(
SELECT a.*,
COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY PatientID) cnt
        FROM myTable  a
 WHERE Feature_Of_Interest = 'present '
)
SELECT *
  FROM qry
WHERE cnt >1
```

Comment: What is the advantage of using a CTE and a ranking function over using a join and an aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a counting query for visits:

```
SELECT PatientID, COUNT(*) as numvisits FROM myTable
GROUP BY PatientID HAVING(numvisits > 1);
```

Then you can base further queries off this one by joining.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer as I head off to bed, so its untested code but, in short, you can use a sub query..

```
SELECT PatientID,Date,...
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Feature_Of_Interest is present
    AND patientid in (select PatientID, count(patientid) as counter
    FROM myTable
    WHERE Feature_Of_Interest is present group by patientid having counter>1)
```

Im surprised your attempt didnt work, it sounds a little like it should have, except you didnt say having count > 1 hence it probably just returned them all.

Comment: After comparing this with answer - I realized my main problem is the same reason this won't work - you can't count something in the select statement, because select is processed last (just before Order by). The linchpin in the answer was the HAVING COUNT(*) > 1, which apparently you CAN do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get what you need by using a [window function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) similar to this:

```
WITH ctePatient AS (
  SELECT PatientID, Date, SUM(1) OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID) Cnt
  FROM tblPatient
  WHERE Feature_Of_Interest = 1
)
SELECT * 
  FROM ctePatient
  WHERE Cnt > 1
```